# Keep one user logged for a year?

Tags: plugins, php, functions, users, cookies

This has got to be simple: how do I keep one user - `my-user` - logged in for a year? (I'm checking logged in cookies in the dev tools console).

**Update 8/16/15**

This works:

```
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year', 10, 3 );

function keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year( $ttl, $user_id, $remember ) {
    if( 1 === $user_id )
        $ttl = YEAR_IN_SECONDS;
   return $ttl;
}
```

And with the array option, this works for multiple users:

```
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year', 10, 3 );

function keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year( $ttl, $user_id, $remember ) {
    if( in_array( $user_id, array( 1, 2 ) ) )
        $ttl = YEAR_IN_SECONDS;
   return $ttl;
}
```

**Update 8/12/15:** *Re: Rarst's answer below: since `get_currentuserinfo` is pluggable, how would I use `apply_filters` in this context?*

I'm getting a `Call to undefined function get_currentuserinfo()` error with this function below used in a simple plugin:

```
global $user_login;
   get_currentuserinfo();
   if ($user_login == "my-user") {

function keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year( $expirein ) {
   return 31556926; // 1 year in seconds
}
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year' );

}
```

But the Codex usage uses the `global`: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo

This, of course, keeps all users logged in for a year:

```
function keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year( $expirein ) {
   return 31556926; // 1 year in seconds
}
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year' );
```

Comment: I think @Rarst has already solved it (therefore already upvoted it) and it looks like you're almost there with your `keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year` filter callback. You don't have to use `apply_filters`, just adjust your filter callback with the three input arguments: `$ttl`, `$user_id` and `$remember`. Then you can add the logic inside, the callback. The `YEAR_IN_SECONDS` constant might come handy here as well.

Comment: @birgire, thanks, I'm not clear on how to do the two methods -  either apply_filters or add_filter - and added a bounty to ask for a full, working example for myself and others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get_currentuserinfo()` is a pluggable function, it is not available during plugins load stage.

That aside you shouldn't be adding filter conditionally, but use data provided by the filter. If you take a look at filter calls:

```
apply_filters( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 14 * DAY_IN_SECONDS, $user_id, $remember )
```

`$user_id` is provided as second argument. You just have your filter listen for it and modify return conditionally on it.

Here's an untested example:

```
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year', 10, 3 );

function keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year( $ttl, $user_id, $remember ) {
    if( 123 === $user_id )
        $ttl = YEAR_IN_SECONDS;
   return $ttl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Let me take a look a this; I'm not sure how to use `apply_filters` in that context.

Comment: @birgire: Thanks! Works fine. I wasn't having any luck using arguments in the filter; something I need to learn. One more question: why doesn't an array work? Like `if (in_array(1,10) === $user_id )` ? Because of the arguments?

Comment: super - did you try `if( in_array( $user_id, array( 1, 10 ) ) )` ? @markratledge

Comment: Thanks again! That way of using of `in_array` works fine.